# why is the main method is not found in the class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a simple Java program, but it shows that main method is not found in the class. But it is there:

```
class AB {
    public void dog() {
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}

class C extends AB {    
    public void cat() {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
}

class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AB obj1 = new AB();
        C obj2 = new C();
        AB obj3 = new C();
        obj1.dog();
        obj2.cat();
        obj2.dog();
        obj3.dog();
        //obj3.cat();
    }
}
```

Also when I am running from the Eclipse, it is not showing java application from the Run As.

Comment: Are all of those classes in the same source file? What is its name?

Comment: Class source file should be called ABC.java. You should set ABC class as public to avoid this problems in the future (it won't compile if the name of source file is different)

Comment: @Eran what i think is that if all classes are in the same file and also if file name differs then also it doesn't matter bcz no class marked as public and only 1 class has main method.

Comment: rename ur source file ABC.java and then try.It seems it has different name.

Comment: thanks @GoodBadandUgly..i got my answer..my problem is solved..Thank you very much...

Comment: @Eran..i got my answer..my problem is solved..Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Go to **run configuration** --> **java application** then select your class `ABC` and Run it.

[Check Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/images/run_config_2.jpg)

Comment: if the file name is ABC, then no need to go to the run configuration, in Run As IDE (at least in Eclipse) will provide the option to run the java program.

Comment: yes that's true.But I am just trying to point out the simplest way to run the program.don't think i am disagree with ur solution.